# It's I who wants X

Tags: verbes

I'm generally thinking about the construction; "It is I who" + verb. Does the verb conjugate for the first person or the third person, seeing as (I do believe) "I" in this situation would be "moi"?

Therefore, does one say:

"C'est moi qui veut" manger or "C'est moi qui veux manger"?

Comment: `veux` `C'est X qui`: Translate it to the corresponding subject (I, you, etc.) and conjugate as such (https://www.francaisfacile.com/exercices/exercice-francais-2/exercice-francais-28456.php https://www.projet-voltaire.fr/regles-orthographe/moi-qui-fais-ou-moi-qui-fait-toi-qui-mange-ou-toi-qui-manges/)

Comment: @Larme Yes, it is indeed *c'est moi qui veu**x** manger*, but comments are for comments and answers for.... answers ;-)

Comment: What is notable but not really unexpected is that it does not work with the attribute of the subject: "C'est moi qui ai faim." but "Je suis une personne qui a faim."

Answer (score 3):

The problem with the verb "to want/vouloir" is that you cannot hear the difference. Even for a native speaker, it can be mistaken if you have to write it. With an other verb, it can be much easier to find the solution (if you have a good French of course) because you will hear the difference.

With the verb "to be/être" for example :
"C'est moi qui suis..." and "c'est lui/elle qui est..."

It is "C'est moi qui veux", definitely.

Answer (score 1):

In your sentence, **qui** is the subject of the subordinate sentence, and **qui** is a pronoun that replaces "moi", therefore "vouloir" must be used at the first person ==>

```
C'est moi qui veux !
```

Note that **qui** will also je either masculine/feminine depending on what it replaces, e.g.

```
C'est elle qui est venue.
```

And **qui** replaces the nominal group that is **directly before** it, therefore you say (as mentioned by @Distic)

```
C'est moi la personne qui a faim.
```

because `qui = la personne` in this example

---

As a remark, there is no such consensus in English: it [seems](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/6195/is-it-is-i-who-decides-correct) that you can write both

```
It's I who want
```

and

```
It's I who wants
```

even if the first is more frequent.

But in French, it would definitely be a **mistake** to write

```
C'est moi qui veut (**WRONG**)
```

Comment: About the mistake in french, an easy way to remember what to say/write is to try with "nous": *C'est nous qui* **voulons**